# Get value from event listener and apply it to global variable

Tags: javascript

I apologize if that title is confusing, so let me explain. I'm creating a Hangman Game to improve my HTML/CSS/Javascript skills. The HTML/CSS is all complete and functions, but the issue is with my javascript.

Basically my javascript works like this:
A user clicks the start button, the game function begins. Once the game begins, the user can type a letter and click 'submit.'  The user's input should update the global variable, userInput but it does not. If my understanding is right (from looking around stack overflow unsure of the exact phrasing of my problem), this is something that cannot be done because of the async and scope nature of javascript. Is this correct? If not, is there any advice I can get on making it work?

```
let userInput = '';
function getValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  userInput = document.getElementById('inputText').value.toLowerCase();
  form.addEventListener('click', form.reset());
  //console.log(userInput); <-- works
}

function hangMan(e) {
  submit.addEventListener('click', getValue);
  const word = getWords(words);
  const MAX_ATTEMPTS = word.length + 3;
  console.log(userInput) <-- does not
  let attempt = 0;
  let win = false;
  dashedWord = getWordBlanks(word);
  wordBlanks.innerHTML = dashedWord;

  while (attempt <= MAX_ATTEMPTS && win === false) {
    let checkedWord = checkAndReplaceCharacter(word, dashedWord, userInput);
    if (checkedWord === word) {
      win = true;
    } else {
      wordBlanks.innerHTML = checkedWord;
    }
    attempt += 1;
  }
}

function main() {
  startButton.addEventListener('click', hangMan);
}

main();
```

Comment: was `startButton` defined somewhere ?

Comment: Your `while` loop will run through completely, without giving the user time to input stuff. Put most of the code inside `getValue` instead

Comment: The game initialization belongs to the function `hangMan()`, however, the gamelogic should belong to `getValue()`

Comment: Note that everytime you click start, you add an event listener `click` to the button `submit`

Comment: Sorry yes, start button is up at the top:
const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
- Working on putting code in right spot - I'll respond if I get it working or not.

Answer (score 0):

The async and scope seem to be fine.
You can change a global variable from inside an event listener.

`console.log(userInput) <-- does not` displays an empty string because at the time it executes `userInput` still holds the default value `let userInput = '';` i.e. the whole `hangMan(e)` method is executed before any click on the submit button so the listener is not yet executed.

Keep in mind, though. If you actually allow the form to be submited, you reload the papge and loose all variables.